# must write something before save

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have a edit text that i hopefully will be able to save soon, but to be able to save i have you would have to write something, i just need the code for checking if there is anything written in the edit text.

when i press the goback button i want to go back if i have not written anything, and i want to save if it has something written in it.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anteckningsblock);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.GoBack);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                maybeSave();
                Intent i = new Intent(anteckningsblock.this, Notelist.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    void maybeSave(){
        String yourText = EditText.getText().toString();
        if(yourText!=null && yourText.isEmpty()){

            //nothing written

        }
        else{
            save();
        }
    }

    void save() {
        try {
            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "anteckning.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            dos.writeUTF("Namnet på anteckningen");
            dos.writeUTF("Innehållet");
            dos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
      String yourText = yourEditText.getText().toString();

      if(yourText!=null && yourText.isEmpty()){

      //nothing written

      }else{

        save();
       }
```

And if You want to be sure, that the String is not only some whitespaces, write after You get the String:

```
     yourText = yourText().trim();
```

that will remove whitespace at the end, or all if the String consists only whitespaces

### SECOND PROBLEM

Your second problem about the error when You get the text from Your editText is, that You trying to get a text like this:

```
 String yourText = EditText.getText().toString();
```

But this makes no sense, You just try to get a text from the Object EditText. But this never will work. What You need is really Your own EditText Object name. You wrote that You will get the text from Your EditText, so I suspect You have initialized it anywhere similar like this:

```
private EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
```

Then it must be:

```
 String yourText = editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Error:(42, 35) error: non-static method getText() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: can You please update Your code how You have done it?